# Error in opening designer workflow after migration from MOSS 2007 to SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, migration

We recently migrated from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2013. Site is working properly. But we are getting error "`SharePoint Designer cannot display the item`" while opening workflow in designer. I am using SharePoint Designer 2013.

Below is the screenshot of the error message:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up in creating new workflow using designer and then deleting old migrated workflow from MOSS 2007.